# I want a variable to change between 0,1,2,3 and go back to 0 after 3 on a key press

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make 'profiles' for my ahk code. So e. g. I want my keys to do something for different cases and therefore I will have a master variable that loops between 0,1,2 and 3 whenever I press e.g. CTRL+TAB.
I have no idea how to do that. In my mind it would be nice to work something like that: 
if CTRL+TAB is pressed ---> variable = sequence.next()
and the sequence would go back to 0 after it reached 3
I know that that is not even close to the code it should be like but I only wanted to show how I imagined the code to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will start at the number `0`, creases up to `3` and starts again at `0`. You can increase the number with pressing `Numpad0` and print out the current number in a messagebox with `Numpad1`.

```
startVar := 0

Numpad0::
if(startVar == 3) {
    startVar := 0
    return
}
startVar++
return

Numpad1::
MsgBox, %startVar%
return
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: In order to address OP's first two sentences (profiles), I would suggest adding information about `#If` for a complete answer.

Comment: I thought that this is what the OP needs. Could you explain it a bit more what do you mean by "adding more information about #If"?

Comment: More information about `#If` can be found here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: Oh my goodness. I wanted to make a class that actually acted as a looping list with a .next() method and looked into AHK's-OOP-documentation. Your solution is way better. Thank you!